# Installing package from 3d-party repository

Tags: package-management, software-installation, ppa, repository

I need to install package from [a non-ppa repository](http://repos.lpm.org.ru/kumir2/ubuntu/). So, the usual `sudo apt-add-repository... & apt-get update` isn't woring.

Of course, I can manually download all necessary packages from [here](http://repos.lpm.org.ru/kumir2/ubuntu/pool/universe/k/kumir2/), but I will have to install these packages and resolve dependencies manually. So, this isn't solving of my problem.

How can I install this 3d-party application?

It is interesting, that the structure of this repository repeats the structure of archievev.ubuntu.com repositories.

Comment: I'm almost certain that the command is `sudo add-apt-repository`.

Comment: @Zacharee1, but how I should use it? It doesn't works if I add the `ppa:` prefix before repository. Aloso it doesn't works if I don't do it.

Comment: @VeLKerr you have to use the full line `sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://repos.lpm.org.ru/kumir2/ubuntu trusty universe"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The manpage of `add-apt-repository` says:

```
   REPOSITORY can  be  either  a  line  that  can  be  added  directly  to
   sources.list(5),  in the form ppa:<user>/<ppa-name> for adding Personal
   Package Archives, or a distribution component to enable.

   In  the   first   form,   REPOSITORY   will   just   be   appended   to
   /etc/apt/sources.list.
```

So, we need to use the full source line:

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://repos.lpm.org.ru/kumir2/ubuntu trusty universe"
```