# How to add packages to /etc/apt/sources.list

Tags: apt, dpkg, debian, synaptic, aptitude

I have been trying to figure this out for a while and I just don't understand it. I need the most basic answer you could possibly give me. What I don't understand is how I install packages from the Debian website with a package manager. When I go to the Debian website and click on the package that I want to download it says: 
"If you are running Debian, it is strongly suggested to use a package manager like aptitude or synaptic to download and install packages, instead of doing so manually via this website." 

Now I have no idea how to use one of those package managers to download something from the Debian website. I do however know how to do something like `aptitude install python`. 
I read somewhere that I need to edit the /etc/apt/sources.list and then use apt-get update, however I am 99% sure I did it completely wrong because I got all sorts of errors. Basic what I am asking is how do I install a package from the Debian website without downloading it form the website and manually executing `dpkg -i package` or `gdebi package`.

I am using Debian Jessie thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: In debian and Ubuntu you use `apt` which sits on top of `dpkg` nd useage is simply: `sudo apt install package_name`, please post the errors your getting.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/680252/installing-package-from-3d-party-repository) might help. Modify the command by replacing the `deb` string found at the Debian website.

Now let's say we want to install `python`(assuming it's not already in our repository).

When you navigate to the package page, scroll down.

Choose an architecture that matches your system, typically amd64.

[image]

That pops you onto the next page, where you're given the `deb` line at the top:

[image]

Now that we have our `deb` line, we can proceed with the command:

`sudo add-apt-repository 'deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian jessie main '`

I almost forgot, you'll need to update your repository afterwards:

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get install python`

Comment: thank you for the help, however I do not know where I can find the link that I am supposed to put after add-apt-repository.

Comment: Please indicate which version of Ubuntu/Debian you are using, and what package you are looking for.

Comment: just updated it.

Comment: [Here](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/amd64/) packages are listed by category for Debain Jessie 64-bit.

Comment: Oh, I see. after you add the repository then you can install it with <code>apt-get install python</code>

Comment: Don't forget the intermediate step: `sudo apt-get update`

Comment: so I tried what you said and I searched apt for this, however I cannot install this https://packages.debian.org/sid/qml-module-qtwayland-compositor package. any ideas?

Comment: This package was released for a different version of Debian (sid). So you might have to compile from source if you need that package. But I cant help you here further since it's off-topic for this post.

Comment: ok. thanks for the help. i wont ask any more questions

Comment: Debian is off-topic here...  -1